# Center aligning text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My main `h1` and `p` tags for this page refuses to center. I'm a new and learning and it's probably something simple I've overlooked; however I cant put my finger on it!

I've tried multiple ways to center this (`.content` and `.header`, even `*`) all set to `text-align: center;` but nothing works. Even `*`! So there has to be something "blocking" this?

Thank you in advance for any tips you can give!

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
margin: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #333;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.v-header{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.video-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-wrap video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #225470;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.55;
}

.content {
  z-index: 2;
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  background: #34b3a0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.section {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.section-b {
  background: #34b3a0;
  color: #fff;
}

@media(max-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Container section will contain the entire landing page -->
  <header class= "v-header container">
  <!-- Video-Wrap section will contain the video -->
    <div class= "video-wrap">
      <video src="images/media2.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
    </div>
  <!-- Overlay section will be over the video, styled with CSS -->
      <div class= "overlay">  </div>
  <!-- Content will contain the actual content on the landing page with links to other pages -->
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Coffee R Us</h1>
      <p>If you like coffee, you'll love us!</p>
      <a href="#" class= "btn">About us</a>
      <a href="#" class= "btn">Our Menu</a>
    </div>

  </header>

<!-- Sections will appear BELOW the wrapper video -->
  <section class="section-a">
    <div>
      <h1>Section A - Thing 1</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint laborum veniam quae non nesciunt enim deleniti soluta molestias molestiae dolorem.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section-b">
    <div>
      <h1>Section B - Thing 1</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint laborum veniam quae non nesciunt enim deleniti soluta molestias molestiae dolorem.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A debugging tip for the future: Add a background color to the elements you are struggling with. If you in this case add `.content { background: red }` you will see it's pretty narrow and left aligned. As [Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47424139/2311559) and [Temani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47424170/2311559) has answered this can be solved by either centering the element or expanding its width :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.content` to center it - that's the element in which all these texts are wrapped, and it doesn't span the whole window width, so you have to center it.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
margin: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #333;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.v-header{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.video-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-wrap video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #225470;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.55;
}

.content {
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  background: #34b3a0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.section {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.section-b {
  background: #34b3a0;
  color: #fff;
}

@media(max-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Container section will contain the entire landing page -->
  <header class= "v-header container">
  <!-- Video-Wrap section will contain the video -->
    <div class= "video-wrap">
      <video src="images/media2.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
    </div>
  <!-- Overlay section will be over the video, styled with CSS -->
      <div class= "overlay">  </div>
  <!-- Content will contain the actual content on the landing page with links to other pages -->
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Coffee R Us</h1>
      <p>If you like coffee, you'll love us!</p>
      <a href="#" class= "btn">About us</a>
      <a href="#" class= "btn">Our Menu</a>
    </div>

  </header>

<!-- Sections will appear BELOW the wrapper video -->
  <section class="section-a">
    <div>
      <h1>Section A - Thing 1</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint laborum veniam quae non nesciunt enim deleniti soluta molestias molestiae dolorem.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section-b">
    <div>
      <h1>Section B - Thing 1</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint laborum veniam quae non nesciunt enim deleniti soluta molestias molestiae dolorem.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm too new to move up any answers for points, but thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that even if your text is centered in your div, your div itself doesn't use all the width available so you end up having a centered text in a misplaced container.

From there, your have 2 solutions to fix your `.content` CSS:

- Center it with a `margin: auto;`
- Expand it so it'll use all the width and you'll be able to align your element in it correctly: `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

.content{ width:100%} add width 100% on .content class

Answer (score 0):

The *problem* is that you have made the container of the `.content` element (*the `.v-header`*) to be `display:flex`. This makes the `.content` element only occupy the space required by its contents (*it no longer expands to 100% of container*).

So now you need to add `justify-content:center` to align the whole box to the center.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
margin: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #333;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.v-header{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  justify-content:center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.video-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-wrap video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #225470;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.55;
}

.content {
  z-index: 2;
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  background: #34b3a0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.section {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.section-b {
  background: #34b3a0;
  color: #fff;
}

@media(max-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Container section will contain the entire landing page -->
  <header class= "v-header container">
  <!-- Video-Wrap section will contain the video -->
    <div class= "video-wrap">
      <video src="images/media2.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
    </div>
  <!-- Overlay section will be over the video, styled with CSS -->
      <div class= "overlay">  </div>
  <!-- Content will contain the actual content on the landing page with links to other pages -->
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Coffee R Us</h1>
      <p>If you like coffee, you'll love us!</p>
      <a href="#" class= "btn">About us</a>
      <a href="#" class= "btn">Our Menu</a>
    </div>

  </header>

<!-- Sections will appear BELOW the wrapper video -->
  <section class="section-a">
    <div>
      <h1>Section A - Thing 1</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint laborum veniam quae non nesciunt enim deleniti soluta molestias molestiae dolorem.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section-b">
    <div>
      <h1>Section B - Thing 1</h1>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint laborum veniam quae non nesciunt enim deleniti soluta molestias molestiae dolorem.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```